# PowerShell SnapIn issues in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to execute the following:

```
StringBuilder errorList = new StringBuilder();
            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            PSSnapInException snapEx = null;
            PSSnapInInfo psinfo = runspaceConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapEx);
            Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfig);
            runSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
```

I get the following error:
`No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2.`

I am new to PoweShell and not sure exactly what that error means. Is this something that I need to install?

EDIT: Full Code

```
        /// 
        /// Creates mailbox for the given user.
        /// 
        /// Email address of user.
        public void EnableMailbox(string userEmail)
        {
            StringBuilder errorList = new StringBuilder();
            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            PSSnapInException snapEx = null;
            PSSnapInInfo psinfo = runspaceConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapEx);
            Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfig);
            runSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
            if (!MailBoxAlreadyExist(userEmail, runSpace))
            {
                Command createMailbox = new Command("Enable-Mailbox");
                createMailbox.Parameters.Add("identity", userEmail);
                createMailbox.Parameters.Add("database", "Mailbox Database Name");
                pipeLine.Commands.Add(createMailbox);
                pipeLine.Invoke();
                if (pipeLine.Error != null && pipeLine.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (object item in pipeLine.Error.ReadToEnd())
                    {
                        errorList.Append(item.ToString());
                        errorList.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(errorList.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Mailbox of user " + userEmail + " already exists on exchange server.");
            }
            pipeLine.Dispose();
            runSpace.Close();
            runSpace.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a dinstinction between 32-bit and 64-bit snapins.  It could be that Echange is 32-bit only, in that case set your C# project to target platform x86.  If Exchange is 64-bit only set the C# project to target platform x64.

Answer (score 3):

As Keith points out, you'll need the right target platform. Exchange is 64-bit only. You'll need to set your C# project to target platform x64. On new projects, it's set to x86 by default (at least with Visual Studio 2010).

Answer (score 0):

You should open remote powershell session to run PS commands from c#.
Executing Exchange snapin locally  from c# code is not supported any more.
Here is the sample for enumerate existing mailboxes:

```
var ExchangeCredential = new PSCredential(user, password.ToSecureString());
string serverName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", GetMachinename(), GetDomainName());
var serverUri = new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}/powershell?serializationLevel=Full", serverName));

var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(serverUri,"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", ExchangeCredential);

runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
PowerShell psh = PowerShell.Create();
psh.Runspace = ru

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
var command = new Command("Get-MailboxDatabase");
command.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Status", true));

pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
commandResults = pipeline.Invoke();
```